# Angular js : Filter data using ng-class

Tags: asp.net, angularjs

i can not filtred MyJson Data "InstallationsDefaultTypes" have you an idea please. How i can filter mythe nested JSON
i just using ng-class to filter it's possible?

Angular Controller :

```
  $scope.GetDefaultByInstallation = function ()
     {
         $scope.installationsStates = [];
         Object.keys($scope.installationsHelper).forEach(function (key)
         {
             var res = false;
             angular.forEach($scope.installationsHelper[key].InstallationsDefautsTypes, function (value, key)
             {
                 if (value.value == true)
                 {
                     res = true;
                 } 
             });
             $scope.installationsStates.push({
                 name: $scope.installationsHelper[key].InstallationsDefautsTypes.name,
                 state: res
             });
         });

     }
```

page.chtml : this is my page html

```
   <div class="row col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 stateDefaut">
        <div class="row  col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 ">
            <div ng-repeat="value in installationsHelper" class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 text-left">
                    <span ng-class="{value.InstallationsDefautsTypes.value | filter : value.InstallationsDefautsTypes.name = "Delestage"  ? 'mDefault' : 'mActive'}">
                        OUI
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

JSON:

```
scope.installationsStates = [ {
                        Installations: {
                            id: 1
                        },
                        InstallationsDefautsTypes :
                     {
                         Delestage:
                         {
                            name: "Delestage", 
                            value : false, 
                            id: 1
                         }
                       defaut command:
                            {
                            name: "defaut1", 
                            value : false, 
                            id: 1
                         }
                       }

                       defaultsInstallations: {
                            0: "defaut",
                            1:Delestage
                        }
                    }]
```

Comment: Where is your table "installationsStates" HTML?

Comment: Hello it's in the <span> :) have you an idea please zaki

Comment: You should use ng-repeat

Comment: How i can do that please can you modify this code please

Comment: I am not getting a clear idea exactly how you want to display your data. From the above code what I am assuming is that you want to show name and state in a tabular format. If is it so then I can form a sample code. Please help me out with your exact requirement

Comment: Okey Zaki , My problem is 
for each default  when the  InstallationsDefautsTypes.value = true i change color of the <span>oui<span>

Comment: i can not go to  chat i don't have access the chat an yes you can change the code please

Comment: you understand my problem zaki?

Comment: Yeah will help you out in sometime

Comment: thank you zaki i waiting  thak you very much

Comment: i change my html code but he display to me  "NON"  
two fold i think because i have two defaults(delestage, defaut ) how i can display just one by defaut

Comment: I am confused I am not getting what exactly you are asking for

Comment: you see the html code zaki?

Comment: Yeah but what exactly you want as an output I am not getting

Comment: have you a facebokk or mail zaki? i will sent to you a attachment is possible

Comment: i want if the default is a true i change color of  span have you a facebook ? i will sent to you an attachment i d'ont speak english very well :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding I made following example as per assumptions

```
    <html ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
        <title></title>     
    </head>
    <body>

        <div ng-controller="myController">
            <div ng-repeat="value in installationsStates">
                <span style="color: {{ value.InstallationsDefautsTypes.value ? 'red' : 'black' }};">
                    OUI
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script>

            angular.module('myApp', []).controller('myController', function($scope) {
                $scope.installationsStates = [
                    {
                        Installations: {
                            id: 1
                        },
                        InstallationsDefautsTypes : {
                            name: "Delestage", 
                            value : false, 
                            id: 1
                        },
                        defaultsInstallations: {
                            0:"defaut",
                            1:"Delestage"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        Installations: {
                            id: 2
                        },
                        InstallationsDefautsTypes : {
                            name: "Delestage", 
                            value : true, 
                            id: 2
                        },
                        defaultsInstallations: {
                            0:"defaut",
                            1:"Delestage"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        Installations: {
                            id: 3
                        },
                        InstallationsDefautsTypes : {
                            name: "Delestage", 
                            value : false, 
                            id: 3
                        },
                        defaultsInstallations: {
                            0:"defaut",
                            1:"Delestage"
                        }
                    },
                ];              
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

For better understanding about ng-repeat etc. please go though this link https://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_ng-repeat.asp

Hope it helps

Comment: yes thank you and why he display to me tow time "OUI" in my html please zaki just the last question

Comment: May be because you have two items in the array

Comment: how i can filter items Zaki please

Comment: how  I can use one item at a time

Comment: Have a look on this link: https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_filters.asp
and give some time to learning. You will understand

Comment: zaki thank you for all : just how i can filter the items please

Comment: Zaki are you here